How to force python xgboost to run CPU-only on MacOS?
I have been running xgboost 1.51 in python 3.9.12 under MacOS 12.6.6, training models using CPU.
I just tried upgrading to xgboost 1.60 (required for SHAP). Now my XGBCLassifier model-training fails with a complaint that my xgboost was not compiled with GPU support. I don't actually want GPU support, a CPU-only model is fine for me.
GPT4 suggested adding tree_method='hist' to my XGBClassifier to force CPU-only, but that doesn't seem to have changed anything.
Here's a minimal test case of the installation:
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                                                                                                            
import xgboost as xgb
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create dummy data                                                                                                                                               
X_train = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 10))
y_train = np.random.randint(2, size=100)

# Initialize the model                                                                                                                                            
model = xgb.XGBClassifier(tree_method='hist', objective='binary:logistic', max_depth=4, learning_rate=0.1, n_estimators=40)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("Model trained successfully on CPU.")

and the error trace:
% ./test_xgboost.py                   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/timconverse/Dropbox/venture_prediction/code/oneoffs/./test_xgboost.py", line 12, in <module>
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "/Users/timconverse/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 532, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/timconverse/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py", line 1382, in fit
    train_dmatrix, evals = _wrap_evaluation_matrices(
  File "/Users/timconverse/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py", line 401, in _wrap_evaluation_matrices
    train_dmatrix = create_dmatrix(
  File "/Users/timconverse/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py", line 1396, in <lambda>
    create_dmatrix=lambda **kwargs: DMatrix(nthread=self.n_jobs, **kwargs),
  File "/Users/timconverse/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 532, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/timconverse/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 654, in __init__
    self.set_info(
  File "/Users/timconverse/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 532, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/timconverse/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 719, in set_info
    self.set_label(label)
  File "/Users/timconverse/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 850, in set_label
    dispatch_meta_backend(self, label, 'label', 'float')
  File "/Users/timconverse/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/data.py", line 1035, in dispatch_meta_backend
    _meta_from_numpy(data, name, dtype, handle)
  File "/Users/timconverse/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/data.py", line 976, in _meta_from_numpy
    _check_call(_LIB.XGDMatrixSetInfoFromInterface(handle, c_str(field), interface_str))
  File "/Users/timconverse/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 203, in _check_call
    raise XGBoostError(py_str(_LIB.XGBGetLastError()))
xgboost.core.XGBoostError: [14:10:03] /Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/xgboost-split_1645117948562/work/src/data/../common/common.h:157: XGBoost version not compiled with GPU support.
Stack trace:
  [bt] (0) 1   libxgboost.dylib                    0x0000000133342364 dmlc::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal() + 116
  [bt] (1) 2   libxgboost.dylib                    0x000000013338d31c xgboost::MetaInfo::SetInfo(char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) + 92
  [bt] (2) 3   libxgboost.dylib                    0x0000000133343a0c XGDMatrixSetInfoFromInterface + 252
  [bt] (3) 4   libffi.7.dylib                      0x000000010bf2fead ffi_call_unix64 + 85
  [bt] (4) 5   ???                                 0x0000000307439bd0 0x0 + 13006773200

I tried upgrading xgboost from 1.51 to 1.60, and expected my previous XGBClassifier code to still work.
What actually resulted was that my calls to xgb.fit() failed with a complaint that xgboost had not been compiled with GPU support.
Then I tried adding the parameter tree_method='hist' to my initialization of XGBClassifier()
I expected that this might cause xgboost to operate in CPU-only mode, and that that might fix the issue with xgboost not having been compiled with GPU support.
Instead, I have the same crash and error message when calling xgb.fit()

Can you try using XGBoost version 2.0.0 or better, then passing device="cpu" to XGBClassifier()? According to the docs, this should force it to use the CPU.
